# Improving a checking fasta file

Tags: python-3.x

Hi guys I need to right a code for check if a file is really a valid
fasta file.

fasta: symmbol > to header followed by a sequence.

```
> header1  
ADDFFGGVVSS

> header2  
GBHHYYTTRRR
```

There are any way to get this dumb function way better?

```
def is_header(line):
    """Checks if the line is a header line in fasta file."""
    return line[0] == '>'

def check_fasta(filename):
    """Checks if the file is a valid fasta file."""
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if not line.startswith(">") and sum(g for g,_ in groupby(fh, key=is_header)) == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

using:

```
check_fasta('data/regions.txt')
```

Result:

```
False or True
```

Not a nice result. Maybe put a print statement or a return False?

Thanks

Comment: right now you check each line; this will raise the error as soon as there's no ">" - is that what you want? also, you re-open the file for each line you check?

Comment: This isn't the answer to your problem but -- In your `groupby` call, you open filename... but you have already opened it in your with statement. Remove the `open(filename)` in your `groupby` call and replace it with `fh`.

Comment: @MrFuppes Hi in reality I want tocheck all file, because the snipet stops when it found the first '>' assuming it is a fasta file, but when I use it in a empty file or a partial fasta (with some no '>'  starting lines) it returns True. I want that check the intire file.

Comment: Maybe you could make use of an existing package like [SeqKit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/)? It's not in Python but you should still be able to call its executable from a Python etc. script. Writing your own filechecker can be a pain ;-)

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl I am at loss with: and sum(g for g,_ in groupby(fh, key=is_header)) == 0: any hint to it

Comment: It checks if the group len is equal to zero if so the fasta file is empty.